# strpost can't find > character

Tags: php

I need to find an image tag in a text entered in TinyMCE. 
I'm triyng to find the position of 'img', and then, the first '>' starting on the position where appears 'img'. 
So, I'm doing:

```
strpos($text, '>')
```

but this don't return anything.
What I'm doin wrong?
thanks!!

---

Thanks for the answers!!!
I've found my problem:

```
$text = $act->getText(ESC_RAW)
```

Without ESC_RAW, symbols like < and > are omitted.

Comment: TinyMCE might replace such symbols with their html-entities (&gt; &lt;) to prevent html-parsing failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and one more thing. if you use strpos result in if statement, like

```
if (strpos($text, '>')) {do_something();}
```

and > symbol is first in $text variable, strpos wil return 0 that is the same with false in php. you need use somthing like

```
if (strpos($text, '>') !== false) {do_something();}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers!!!
I've found my problem:

    $text = $act->getText(ESC_RAW)

Without ESC_RAW, symbols like < and > are omitted.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked your input? eventually TinyMCE has already converted it into html entities and your '`>`' became a '`&gt;`' ...?

Comment: Thanks for the answers!!!
I've found my problem:

    $text = $act->getText(ESC_RAW)

Without ESC_RAW, symbols like < and > are omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Works [fine](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/75099.php) for me

```
<?php 
$text = "<testing>"; 
echo strpos($text, '>')
```

result: 8

Warning: `&gt;` isn't `>` !

Comment: Thanks for the answers!!!
I've found my problem:

    $text = $act->getText(ESC_RAW)

Without ESC_RAW, symbols like < and > are omitted.